# Do the temporary hit points I get each turn from the UA Order of the Immortal Mystic's Psionic Resilience feature stack?

Tags: dnd-5e, unearthed-arcana, stacking, temporary-hit-points, mystic

Right now I am playing a [Mystic (UA)](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UAMystic3.pdf), and I have chosen the Order of the Immortal as my discipline. The [Psionic Resilience](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UAMystic3.pdf#page=7) subclass feature gives me temporary hit points equal to my Int mod at the start of each turn; my Intelligence score is 20, so I get 5 temp HP each turn.

If I have gained temporary HP in one turn and I haven't been hit, do I continue gaining the HP? Or do I have to expend the Temporary HP before gaining more?

Comment: Related: [Do multiple sources of temporary hit points combine, or do you only get one set?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/69488/do-multiple-sources-of-temporary-hit-points-combine-or-do-you-only-get-one-set)

Answer (score 15):

### You can set your temporary hit points to 5 at the start of your turn

The rules on [temporary hit points](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#TemporaryHitPoints) state (emphasis mine):

> Healing can't restore temporary hit points, and they can't be added together. **If you have temporary hit points and receive more of them, you decide whether to keep the ones you have or to gain the new ones.** For example, if a spell grants you 12 temporary hit points when you already have 10, you can have 12 or 10, not 22.

So, at the start of your turn, you can give yourself 5 temporary hit points. This would replace what you had left over from the previous turn (if any), although you have the choice (strictly speaking) of keeping the previous amount if you wanted to.

You could never go above 5 temporary hit points using your ability. But if someone gave you some temporary hit points (say 10), you could choose to ignore your ability granting you more temp hit points at the start of each turn until that new pool dropped below 5. I hope that makes sense...

Comment: Thank you so much you guys! I'm working with a UA printout with no PHB near me, so that sorts everything out.

Answer (score 9):

## Temporary hit points never stack.

Every time you have an opportunity to apply temp hp, you choose between the THP you have, and what you can apply. According to the [PHB: Chapter 9, Temporary Hit Points](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#TemporaryHitPoints)

> If you have temporary hit points and receive more of them, you decide
> whether to keep the ones you have or to gain the new ones. For
> example, if a spell grants you 12 temporary hit points when you
> already have 10, you can have 12 or 10, not 22.