# Do the temporary hit points from the Battlerager barbarian's Reckless Abandon stack if I make multiple attacks on my turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, barbarian, stacking, temporary-hit-points

If I'm a [Battlerager barbarian](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#PathoftheBattlerager) (from *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide*, p. 121) and make 3 attacks on my turn while using Reckless Attack and raging, do I get 5 temporary HP total, or 5 temp HP per attack (15 HP total)?

The latter seems a bit high to be able to get per round combined with resistances.

Comment: Related: [Do multiple sources of temporary hit points combine, or do you only get one set?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/69488/do-multiple-sources-of-temporary-hit-points-combine-or-do-you-only-get-one-set)

Answer (score 19):

The Battlerager's Reckless Abandon feature says:

> Beginning at 6th level, **when you use Reckless Attack** while raging, you also gain temporary hit points

The Reckless Attack feature says:

> Starting at 2nd level, you can throw aside all concern
>   for defense to attack with fierce desperation. **When you make your
>   first attack on your turn**, you can decide to attack recklessly. Doing
>   so gives you advantage on melee weapon attack rolls using Strength
>   during this turn, but attack rolls against you have advantage until
>   your next turn.

Since Reckless Attack only triggers when you make your first attack on your turn, it can only be used once per turn (and only on *your* turn, unlike [Sneak Attack](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47692/do-rogues-get-sneak-attack-damage-added-to-attacks-made-outside-their-turn)). Therefore, you can only gain the benefit of Reckless Abandon once per turn.

---

Also, as [Purple Monkey](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/14878/purple-monkey) points out, temporary HP from multiple sources does not stack, so even if you *could* use Reckless Abandon multiple times on your turn, you'd still only have 5 Temp HP: [How does Armor of Agathys interact with getting temporary hit points?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55751/how-does-armor-of-agathys-interact-with-getting-temporary-hit-points)

Comment: Just a heads-up: the question you linked in the answer seems to relate more to the damaging effect of *armor of Agathys*. This question seems to deal more with the issue of stacking temp HP: [Do multiple sources of temporary hit points combine, or do you only get one set?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/69488/do-multiple-sources-of-temporary-hit-points-combine-or-do-you-only-get-one-set)